# How to get a Hazelcast map inside a Camel route?

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, hazelcast

I'm really fresh to Camel (and hazelcast, at that), and I've been playing around with it a bit recently. A seemingly simple operation is causing me a lot of trouble, and I'm struggling to find any waypointers anywhere.

I have a listener watching for changes on a hazelcast map. If said changes match a certain criteria, I want to grab the entire map and send it to a processor. Something like this:

```
from(hazelcast:map:someMap?hazelcastInstance=#hazelcastInstance)
.filter().method(SomeFilter.class, filterMethod)
.???
// If the filter cafeterias are met, get the entire map and send it to a processor
```

But I am really not sure how to, well, get entire map itself, especially using Java DSL. The closest thing I've found is to get the map's `keySet` and then call `getAll(keySet)` on it, which seems needlessly contrived for such a simple thing? If this is really the preferred method, there is another issue - how do you pass said keySet as the parameter to the getAll operation? I.e.:

```
<snip>
.setHeader(HazelcastConstants.OPERATION, constant(HazelcastConstants.GET_KEYS_OPERATION))
.to(hazelcast:map:someMap?hazelcastInstance=#hazelcastInstance) // Gets the keySet just fine.
.setHeader(HazelcastConstants.OPERATION, constants(HazelcastConstants.GET_ALL_OPERATION))
.????
// I've tried .setHeader(HazelcastConstants.OPERATION_PARAM, new 
// SimpleExpression("${body}")> here,
// amongst many other things, but, I just get an empty object back, so it's
// pretty clear I'm messing up 
// the format or parameter choice here.
.to(hazelcast:map:someMap?hazelcastInstance=#hazelcastInstance)
```

Using camel 2.18.0 here, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Well after bit more trial and error, I got it working. I swear it was one of the first things I tried, but I must've bungled it up on the first attempt and got stumped. All you really do is get the keySet and then put into OBJECT_ID. So something like this:

```
.setHeader(HazelcastConstants.OPERATION, constant(HazelcastConstants.GET_KEYS_OPERATION))
.to(hazelcast:map:someMap?hazelcastInstance=#hazelcastInstance)
.setHeader(HazelcastConstants.OPERATION, constants(HazelcastConstants.GET_ALL_OPERATION))
.setHeader(HazelcastConstants.OBJECT_ID, new SimpleExpression("${body}"))
.to(hazelcast:map:someMap?hazelcastInstance=#hazelcastInstance)
```

(Note: it's hazelcast-map in newer versions.)

And ta-dah, you've got a Hashmap to work with. The alternative seems to use QUERY, but I couldn't figure out the proper syntax for, well, the query. I'd love to hear if anyone has a working example with a QUERY header...